# MVVM Light: Register generic class for messenger

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I have a generic ShowMessage class that I want to use to carry data around:

```
class ShowMessage<T> {
    private readonly T _Data;

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public T Data { get { return _Data; } }

    public ShowMessage( T data) {
        _Data = data;
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel I want to register for all possible ShowMessage instances, but currently I haven't found a way. Has anyone registered a generic base class (note: I want to register only once and not n-times to have a clean code)

**Edit:**

To make my problem clearer: I know that I can use the Register method:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<List<string>>(this, StringList);
```

In this case I register for `List<string>`. I want to register for `List<>` to have one handler acting on different payload (as the handler is not required to know anything about the payload)

Comment: What are you using this class for?  Is it for a dialog box?  Why is it needed in every viewmodel.

Comment: It is not required in every viewbox. I want to use the Messenger of MVVM Light to handle UI changes. Not a messagebox but the content of a ContentControl on the main form or an overlay.

Comment: I'm struggling with this exact problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @dotNET unfortunately I have not solved this problem as I switched to a different environment alltogether

Answer (score 0):

the mvvm light messenger allows you to register for a message with a specific object attached, just place that registration in a part of your code that is globally available, however you do that, like in the parent view model,  then you register for messages with type ShowMessage.  Then any time that message is sent by any class, it will be caught as long as the ShowMessage class is attached.

see these:

http://blog.galasoft.ch/lbugnion/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

[MVVM light: Pass object from view to viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628908/mvvm-light-pass-object-from-view-to-viewmodel)

Comment: I do know of the Register api. I want to register a single handler for all types of a generic class though. I'm going to update my question to make it clearer