# Receiving messages with generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, mvvm-light

My VM sends notification messages to the View layer using a special generic class `AppMessage` (derives from `GenericMessage`):

```
public bool ShowDialog<T>(AppMessageType type, T arg) where T : class
{
  bool Result = false;
  Action<bool> Callback = (o) => Result = o;
  Messenger.Default.Send(new AppMessage<T, bool>(type, Callback, arg));
  return Result;
}
```

However, on the receiving end, I'm not sure how to call `Register` for all kinds of `T`. I can `Register` for messages of specific types such as:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<AppMessage<string, bool>>(this, OpenDialog);
```

but that works only for this specific type of argument. How can I register for all kinds of arguments?

N.B. A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593328/mvvm-light-register-generic-class-for-messenger), with no good answer.

Comment: Can you show how `Messenger.Default.Register<AppMessage<?, bool>>(this, OpenDialog);` is called? From where(how) you get information about `T` type?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: That is actually the problem at hand. I want to register for all types of `T`.

Comment: Is <object, bool> not a valable solution? An in the method that handles the receiving part check for type?

Comment: @Depechie: I have settled with `<object, bool>` as a last resort, but as you see, generic version would have its own compile-time benefits.

Comment: Yeah, think that currently there is no easy way to solve this, or really manually register for all specific <T, bool> AppMessage combinations